# Multisort - uppercase/lowercase?

Tags: php

Im trying to sort an array using multisort, by sort field and then by title.

```
foreach ($productContent as $key => $row)
{
    $title[$key] = $row['title'];
$sort[$key] = $row['sort'];
}

array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $title, SORT_ASC, $productContent);
```

This works but it does not take in to account capitalisation fo strings in the title field.

I have looked at the docs, and it suggests creating a lower case array, Ive tested this and it screws up the multisort.

Can anyone give me the way so it sorts title ignoring the case of the string?

Comment: This flag help? `SORT_FLAG_CASE - can be combined (bitwise OR) with SORT_STRING or SORT_NATURAL to sort strings case-insensitively` 5.4+  If not on that version I'd just use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and some recursive iterator method.

Comment: `array_multisort($someArray, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);`

Comment: Doesn't work. Still doesnt take in to account lower case strings

Comment: Try `SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE` instead of `SORT_ASC`

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant SORT_NATURAL - assumed 'SORT_NATURAL'

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant SORT_FLAG_CASE -

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/UeeUZE  What version of PHP?  ...well bah, RTFM.

Comment: This sorts them by title but knocks out the previous sort by sort

Comment: @ficuscr your example doesnt have two sorts.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/boka0i - Have you tried to solve this yourself at all?

Comment: Yes, hence why Im asking on here.